# exe file from gcc -0 file file.c not working in vsc terminal

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VSC so that I can compile and run C and C++ code.

I've installed ms-vscode.cpptools extension.

I've followed this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw and I can run `gcc` and `g++` commands, but when I run the actual exe, nothing happens.

I've found lots of answers on SO, but nothing works. I can't believe how hard it is to run C/C++ code in VSC.

This simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    // declarare
    int m, n;
    FILE *fis;
    char numef[256];
    float **a;

    printf("Introduceti calea catre fisier: ");
    gets(numef);

    fis = fopen(numef, "rb");
    if (fis == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nu s-a putut deschide fisierul %s", *numef);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Am deschis fisierul %s", *numef);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs this:

```
printf("Introduceti calea catre fisier: ");
```

but it should also output either `printf("Nu s-a putut deschide fisierul %s", *numef);` or `printf("Am deschis fisierul %s", *numef);`.

Comment: `gcc file.c -o file` <<-- lowercase 'o'

Comment: Why you want to use `gcc` with Visual Studio? VS is another compiler.

Comment: I have no answer to that. It's just the guide that I found on VSC: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw  
I would like to be able to compile and run C and C++ code.

Comment: @Jorje12 VS is GUI compiler. It has also command line C compiler `cl`. You don't need to install special `gcc` support to learn C/C++.

Comment: @i486 I think this is about Visual Studio Code, the separate Editor offered by Microsoft, not about Visual Studio. Recommending everybody who has a problem with configuring that one to use instead Visual Studio, might be the purpose of that prodcut. ;-)

Comment: It's VSC: https://i.postimg.cc/T29CC7gk/this.png

Comment: How do I run that code ? As you can see from the screenshot Running does nothing and I have to manually close the code because it runs forever.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a segfault on the `printf("...", *numef);` lines. You can remove the `*` before `numef` and it should work as you intend. This is because when you define an array (`char numef[256];`) in C, the name (`numef`) becomes a pointer. Then, when you use it in `printf()` you can simply use the pointer `numef`.